# Memory leak application crashing while converting uiimage to nsdata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

My application crashing while am converting uiimage to nsdata, I got this message in my console.

```
 " Received memory warning"
```

And my application get crashing.

Am using this below code to converting uiimage to nsdata,

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
```

Then am using this below code to convert nsdata to uiimage:

```
   CFDataRef imgData;
    CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider;
    CGImageRef image1;
    imgData = (CFDataRef)CFBridgingRetain([arraydata objectAtIndex:0]);
    imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData (imgData);
    CFRelease(imgData);
    image1 = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGDataProviderRelease(imgDataProvider);

    imageView.image = CFBridgingRelease(image1);

    CGImageRelease(image1);
```

Can any one help me to out of this issue?.

Comment: Its hard to tell what is causing that error only from that code, but first I would make sure that the image sizes aren't too big and that your not in a very large or infinite loop.  I see your using indexPath.row in your code so your looping through data, just make sure its not forever.

Comment: Make sure you are not using very bigger size of images...

Comment: @KananVora  thanks for reply, am picking images from galley so am not resizing images.

Comment: Why you are converting image to NSData? 
You can use direct UIImage object to display in UIImageView

Comment: @RahulPatel friend, am saving that images into data base so only am converting

Comment: ok.. It means you are storing lots of NSData in memory and might causing problem.. If you want to store image than try to store in base64 encoding. That is string and consumes less space

Comment: ok friend, i will try and let u know, And my problem is to converting uiimage to nsdata, that time only my application get crashing

Answer (score 1):

Try converting NSdata to image like this:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```